# Solution of inequality $|x^2-5x|>|x^2| - |5x|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

The correct solution should be $0<x<5$ and $x<0$ . I'm getting $x<0$ and $-5<x<5$ but not $0<x<5$

I did as follows :

$|x^2-5x|>|x^2| - |5x|$

$\implies |x^2|<5x$ so that right side will be -ve and will be always less than left side.

$\implies  -5x<x^2<5x \implies -5<x<5$
Where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Since $x=0$ is impossible, you could start by dividing both sides by $|x|$ and then solving for each of the cases $x>0$, $x<0$ and $x<5$

Comment: There is this triangle inequality :
$$|x|-|y|\le|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$$
I don't think it's applicable here, but it's a useful tool in some cases.

Comment: What makes this inequality "linear"?

Comment: Not sure, but in my school, usually we will do $|x^2|$ - $5x$ <0 first, then we would sketch a graph then shaded the graph below the x-axis. (For this case).

Comment: @mathguy The question was taken from a chapter on linear inequalities and that's why I put there -- corrected it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As observed by @Bernard Masse, a solution $x$ has to be non-zero. So we may divide both sides by $\lvert x\rvert$ and obtain the equivalent system
$$\lvert x-5\rvert >\lvert x\rvert -5\quad\textbf{and}\quad x\neq 0.$$
The inequality is satisfied if $\lvert x\rvert<5\iff -5<x<5$.

So suppose $\lvert x\rvert\ge 5$. We have the chain of equivalences
\begin{align*}
\lvert x-5\rvert >\lvert x\rvert -5&\iff\lvert x-5\rvert^2=(x-5)^2>\bigl(\lvert x\rvert -5\bigr)^2\\
&\iff  x^2 -10x+25 >x^2-10\lvert x\rvert+25\\
&\iff x<\lvert x\rvert\iff x<0
\end{align*}

Grouping these results the set of solutions is
$$(-\infty,-5]\cup(-5,0)\cup(0,5)=\color{red}{(-\infty,0)\cup(0,5)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $|x^2-5x|>|x^2|-|5x|$ implies that the right-hand side must be negative. For example, if $x=-10$ then $|x^2-5x|=150$ while $|x^2|-|5x|=50$.